# watchconnectivity not working on device - only simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, watchconnectivity

I have followed many tutorials online and seen how to connect the watch with the iPhone to be able to send data and have the following code to:

Send:

```
watchSession.sendMessage(["name":"Maz"], replyHandler: nil) { (error) -> Void in

    }
```

Receive:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
    myLabel.setText(message["name"]! as? String)
    //reloadWatchTable()
}
```

The code works when I use the simulator but not when I'm running on my iPhone and Apple Watch.

Comment: Does the sendMessage errorHandler get invoked with an error? In the code above you've left it empty; maybe add a print statement to log the error?

Comment: Yes it does, i just haven't put it there.
Ive tried using applicationContext and it does the same thing.

Comment: @ccjensen 
When using the applicationContext, I did the same on another app and it worked but when i use the following code, "hello3" is printed.

`let applicationDict = ["name":"phone"]
        textLabel.text = "hello1"
        
        do {
            
            try session.updateApplicationContext(applicationDict)
            
            textLabel.text = "hello2"
            
        } catch {
            textLabel.text = "hello3"
            print("error")
        }`

Comment: Try changing the catch to capture the error variable too `catch let error as NSError {     print(error.localizedDescription) }`

Comment: @ccjensen well i tried it on the simulator and no issue comes up. When i use device the issue occurs, and when run on a device, the nothing watch is not connected to the logs and so nothing prints

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the OS if things work in the simulator but not on devices. Did you file a bug report? If so, could you post the radar number so any Apple engineers can easily track it down?